# Are there better methods than Levenberg-Marquardt for large-scale nonlinear least squares problems?

Tags: least-squares, nonlinear

I am using Levenberg-Marquardt to solve a nonlinear least squares problem with 16 million residuals and about a million variables. I have a fast matrix vector product for both the Jacobian and its transpose, and I can also compute the norms of the columns of the Jacobian. To compute the step, I am using LSQR. This scheme is probably best when the Jacobian is formed explicitly, and forming the Jacobian is quite expensive. So once we have it, it pays to solve for the step quite accurately. In my case, it seems wasteful to evaluate the matrix vector product many times at the same point, as opposed to making a small step every time a matrix vector product is evaluated. This would be the case in the conjugate-gradient method, for example, but its convergence is much slower. I’ve tried limiting LSQR to just a few iterations but that doesn’t seem to help.

Is there a better method for when we have only a fast matrix vector product?

Comment: Have you considered using a nonlinear-CG method where you would use the fast matrix-vector product to compute the gradient used by the nonlinear CG method?

Comment: Yes, I have and the convergence is much too slow. But that is the kind of answer I’m looking for.

Comment: Have you added explicit regularization to the nonlinear least squares problem before applying the nonlinear CG method?

Comment: No. What kind of regularization would you add?

Comment: If the parameters are $x$ and residuals are $r$, then consider minimizing $\min \sum_{j=1}^{m} r_{j}^{2}+\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{i}^{2}$, where $\alpha$ is a small positive parameter.  Once $\alpha$ is large enough, the problem will be well conditioned and nonlinear CG will converge in a reasonable number of iterations.

Comment: If your one million parameters represent a discretized version of an image or a 3d volume model, then using Laplacian smoothing for regularization might also make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that.